# How to compress and encrypt the whole directory (var/log)?

Tags: bash, encryption, tar

How to compress and encrypt the whole directory (`var/log`)?

My try:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
tar -zcvf |bzip2|openssl smime -encrypt \
 -aes256 -binary -outform DEM \
 -out ${backup_dir}${backup_name} \
 "${backup_public_key}" -f "/var/log"
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a huge topic. I would recommend you first reading [this stackoverflow answer why to use `gpg` and not `openssl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247821/openssl-vs-gpg-for-encrypting-off-site-backups) and then follow [these steps to do what you want](https://serverfault.com/questions/489140/what-is-a-good-solution-to-encrypt-some-files-in-unix).

In general, once you have already generated your keys in GPG, this can be done by:

```
tar -cz /path/to/a/folder | gpg --encrypt --recipient "KeyName" \
                                --output compressed_folder.tar.gz.gpg
```

Note that GPG also compresses by default so `tar` can be used without the `z` option. You should get your encrypted file faster but in some cases `tar`'s compression algorithm is better.

Depending on a use case you may also be interested in symmetric encryption rather than asymmetric described in the second link. It doesn't require private and public keys generation. If so then use `--symmetric` instead:

```
gpg --output doc.gpg --symmetric doc
```

You will be then asked for a passphrase. For a bit more detailed instruction see [official manual](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pipe with `tar` for packing and compressing and [`ccrypt` [image: Install ccrypt]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ccrypt) for encrypting the data:

```
tar czp /var/log | ccrypt >logs.tgz.cpt
```

`tar` packs the data and filters it through `gzip`, it’s then piped to `ccrypt` which asks for a password and (by default) performs the encryption. Finally the data stream is redirected to `logs.tgz.cpt`. The `cpt` suffix stands for a file encrypted with `ccrypt`, this suffix is removed when you decrypt the file with:

```
ccrypt -d logs.tgz.cpt
```

You can also provide the password via a keyfile with `-k /path/to/keyfile`, `ccrypt` then reads the first line of this file and uses that as the password.

> ccrypt is based on the Rijndael block cipher, a version of which was
>   also chosen by the U.S. government as the Advanced Encryption Standard
>   (AES, see http://www.nist.gov/aes). This  cipher  is
>          believed to provide very strong cryptographic security.

#### Further reading

- [`man ccrypt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/ccrypt.1.html)